# CodeIgniter Model conception

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a DBMS web-application which interacts with a quite big database.

So I thought of writing a "Mother-Model" called 'Table'.
Then, using overloading in PHP I dynamically "create" properties of this table, the properties are:

1. The table name and its primary key given as arguments to the constructor.

   ```
   function __construct($table_name, $table_pk){
   //..
   }
   ```
2. A property/member representing each field of my table. And I get the fields' names by calling:

   ```
   $this->db->list_fields
   ```

I want to ask if this approach has any already known cons, or I could go further in it.

Comment: Look up Codeigniter supermodels. It does what you describe.

Comment: are there any newer releases ?